# sending sms through mobile connected with pc

Tags: c#, .net, sms

I am trying to develop the application which, any mobile is connected with PC and needs to send SMS through the mobile one by one, software is used only to connect the mobile and type the message.

When the send button is clicked the message should send through mobile not through any modems.

I have tried to search everywhere, but I couldn't find anything.

Can anybody guide me on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it on your own without using a sms-library you can open the modem in handset through a serial port and send out hayes at-commands for sms-operation.
Before you program you can try it using a terminal program.

Example

```
; Send message to "0170 00000"  (Ctrl+Z to finish and send the message)
AT+CMGS="017000000" 
> This is a SMS Test!!^Z

+CMGS: 3 ; OK, message gone
```

Note: these at-commands are not supported on every handset. Maybe the handset needs additional configuration through extra at commands (set textmode, set sms-gateway, ...)

Several sms hayes related commands are described in http://www.cellular.co.za/at_etsi.htm .

Comment: thnks k3b, i visited the link, but i could nt understand the coding concepts, how can i proceed...

Comment: For a small tutorial how to communicate with a gsm-modem with a terminalprogram and a c# example see [Sample projects using C#.Net , Communication GSM modem with PC ](http://csharptechniques.blogspot.com/2009/09/c-technical-ideas-sample-project-gsm.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely you can send sms through your pc connected with your cell phones. "Nokia PC Suite" is the only software; after installing software in your computer, connect your Nokia handset by usb cable with computer and select pc suite option. After then launch Nokia PC Suite. Now there u go.

Comment: But that only works for Nokia devices. the question is about 'any mobile' device. And you have to use some software from Nokia and I guess the OP wants to use some code in his own application

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is difficult. It is difficult not because the programming is difficult, but because there are restrictions (security!) from the carrier side and from the mobile manufacturer side.

To be able to send messages from a mobile device connected to a PC, the mobile device must provide access to the internal functions its OS uses to deliver those SMSs. They could be low level modem commands, or a high level API; but in any case it will depend on the device manufacturer SDK.

If you want to type more efficiently, then maybe a mobile device with support for a bluetooth keyboard is a good idea.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, can u please explain it clearly why it is not possible, am new to this mobile application.

Comment: It is not that is not possible, but it depends on many variables. The post by K3b shows some modem commands, but they only work if the device allows you to do that. You have to think about the mobile device, the carrier and the country. For example in Japan, most of the phones are completely locked so you will never have access to those commands. Nokia and Motorola are good if you want to try, you need the drivers and the SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that depends strongly on the used mobile phone. I don't think there's a generic solution for all manufacturers. And such feature is probably hardly documented.

However, I'm not sure, if this is worth the effort at all, because e.g. Nokia provides the software "Ovi Suite" (or older PC Suite), which already supports sending SMS via connected phone. I think there are similar programs from other manufacturers.

Comment: thanks for replying, so ur saying this is not possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send SMS from a computer via a connected phone, but the phone itself will be the modem (I assume you don't want to connect another device for SMS). You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932312/need-c-sample-for-sending-sms-with-nokia-pc-suite), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984631/sms-via-a-nokia-phone-over-a-serial-port) and (possibly) [GSMComm](http://scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm) for more info